# Get sub string in a string on condition to a string in the same line with it

Tags: python, string, python-re

I have two strings which may look as follows.

```
str1 = "* {'id': '741', 'name': 'over'}" \
       "* {'id': '742', 'name': 'cal'}"  \
       "* {'id': '743', 'name': 'cal'}"

str2 = "* {'id': '743', 'name': 'cal'}" \
       "* {'id': '742', 'name': 'cal'}" \
       "* {'id': '741', 'name': 'over'}"
```

Here what I want is no matter where the `over` string is, I can get the same line's   `id`(`741`) with string `over`. Here what I have tried is to use `find` and `rfind`.

```
str1[str1.find('id')+len('id'):str1.rfind('name')] # or str2
```

The problem is there are three `'id'` and `'name'` in the string. How can I do this?

Comment: Are these multiline strings? Is the backslash part of the string or is it line continuation?

Comment: Also, where are these strings coming from? If it's your code that generates them it might as well be changed so it creates a proper Python object (ie a list of dicts)

Comment: @DeepSpace It comes from celery. It is hard to transfer them to python object. The backslash is line continuation.

Comment: You can quite easily have a regex that does this, but I still think you are asking the wrong question. I'm sure there is a way to get a Python object from celery

Comment: @DeepSpace `celery -A proj inspect active` is a command we execute in terminal. Its output are irregular strings.

Comment: Then use `-j` flag to get it as JSON that can easily be converted to a Python object. If then you are not sure how to work with the json string, update the question with the command you are using and the output you are receiving. As of now, this question is an [XY](https://xyproblem.info)
 question.

Comment: @DeepSpace Thanks so much. `-j` is exactly what I am looking for!